# SQL not recognizing unicode enum value

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table that uses enums with special characters created as such:

```
create table test(test enum('Não informado',
'A selecionar',
'Em contratação',
'Ação Preparatória',
'Em licitação de obra',
'Em licitação de projeto',
'Em obras',
'Em execução',
'Concluído',
'Em operação'))
```

And I'm trying to add a row to it:

```
insert into test(test)
values('Concluído')
```

but SQL is giving me the error

```
Error Code: 1265. Data truncated for column 'test' at row 1
```

What am I doing wrong?
How can I fix this?

I am running a MySQL server version 5.6.23-log
MySQL Community

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use utf8 character set and collation in the definition of your enum, like:

```
create table test(test enum('Não informado',
                            'A selecionar',
                            'Em contratação',
                            'Ação Preparatória',
                            'Em licitação de obra',
                            'Em licitação de projeto',
                            'Em obras',
                            'Em execução',
                            'Concluído',
                            'Em operação') 
                       CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci);
```

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1988d/1)